# Searchbar disappear before and after push navigation of result - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

In this case I want to present searchbar which like Calendar app (original app from iPhone), When click on result, it will push navigation to next screen without lose searchbar when pop navigation back. and during push navigation It will be not hide searchbar before go to next screen. as like picture :

[image]

And I try to catch animation like above, but something I got:

[image]
[image]

It's not look like calendar app when try push navigation by click on result. it's animated to hide search bar than push navigation. 
here is my configuration:

```
//add on viewDidload 
self.navigationController?.definesPresentationContext = true

search?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
search?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

any idea, if you don't understand what I meant, let comment.

Comment: I faced the same issue, please check my answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47617501/5251783

Comment: It's not like what I want, I got problem with animate push navigation @Hosny

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: When I searched, than I click on row of result, but search bar hide than push navigation. that animation not look like calendar, I prefer to calendar animation @Hosny